# Understanding the Syntax for COALESCE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coalesce

I am trying to understand the below syntax. Can I get some help with this.

```
DECLARE @StringList VARCHAR(2500); 
SELECT  COALESCE(@StringList + ',','') + CAST(apID as VARCHAR) AS ApIdList FROM testTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result you will get all `apID` from `testTable` in `VARCHAR`

[`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)
checks if first parameter is `NULL` then the second parameter will returned. In this line `@StringList` is always equals `NULL`

```
COALESCE(@StringList + ',','')
```

So, `NULL + ',' = NULL` and you will get empty string (`''`)

Then `empty string  + CAST(apID as VARCHAR)` and you will get `apID` as `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 1):

Coalesce returns the first non-null element provided in the list supplied. See - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx.

In your case, if @StringList is not null, then it's contents will be prepended with a comma to appID for each row in testTable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is returning `ApID` as a string for all rows in the table.  Why?  Because `@StringList` is `NULL` so the first expression evaluates to `''` and the second to a string representation of the `ApId` in some row in the table.

I caution you about the conversion to `VARCHAR` with no length.  Don't do this!  The default length varies by context, and you can introduce very hard-to-debug errors without a length.

A related expression is more common, I think:

```
SELECT @StringList = COALESCE(@StringList + ',', '') + CAST(apID as VARCHAR(8000)) AS ApIdList
FROM testTable;
```

This does string concatenation, so all the values of `apID` are concatenated together in a comma-delimited string.

What this is doing is looping on the result set to assign the variable.  This type of assignment of a variable across multiple rows is discouraged.  I don't think that SQL Server guarantees that it actually works (i.e. is a documented feature), but it appears to work in practice across all versions.